# Tmux displaying strange characters after installing theme through tpm

Tags: linux, fonts, console, tmux

I've recently started using tmux and have been working on getting it configured. After installing the [catppuccin theme](https://github.com/catppuccin/tmux) some of the symbols at the bottom of the screen aren't being displayed properly.

[image]

I am running alacrity on pop os. I have tried re-sourcing my config file, reloading tmux, starting tmux with the -u flag (solution to a similar issue according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410048/utf-8-character-not-showing-properly-in-tmux)), and launching tmux through the gnome terminal to no avail.

This is my tmux.conf:

```
# Set ture color
set-option -sa terminal-overrides ",xterm*:Tc"

# Set prefix
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind C-Space send-prefix

# Shift Alt vim keys to switch windows
bind -n M-H previous-window
bind -n M-L next-window

# List of plugins
set -g @tpm_plugins '              \
        tmux-plugins/tpm               \
        tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible     \
    christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator \
        catppuccin/tmux                \
'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'

set-environment -g TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH '~/.tmux/plugins/'
```

UPDATE: I'm now using 'Fira Code Nerd Font' and my tmux looks like this:

[image]

Comment: according to its doc: "In order to have the correct icons displayed please use your favorite **nerd fonts patched font**."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you didn't install an appropriate font. According to its docs:

```
In order to have the correct icons displayed please use your favorite nerd fonts patched font.
```

You can go to [here](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads) to download and install a font that you like. Some popular fonts are FiraCode, MesloLG,Iosevka.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! You're right I wasn't using a supported font. Unfortunately changing my font didn't fully fix the issue.. not sure why. Just updated my question.

Comment: You could try to change to another font such as MesloLG or upgrade your tmux version. If it still doesn't work, you could switch to others such as powerlevel10k to see if it is a font or theme issue.

Comment: Just found my issue. The terminal was overriding my default monospaced font with it's own. Thanks for the help!